# Easiest options of video chat for asp.net

Tags: video, call, videochat

I'm looking for a way to add video call to my web application which is in ASP.net webforms. Is there any opensource application available ?

**Note:** I need only peer to peer connection!

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Figured that easiest way is to use WebRTC which makes everything much easier.However, minor differences between browsers might cause concerns regarding compatibility. therefore, I suggest if anyone wants to use WebRTC in ASP.net using C# (as I did) can use [XSockets WebRTC API](http://xsockets.net/blog/tutorial-building-a-multivideo-chat-with-webrtc).

There is anouther option which might cause a little more trouble but still worth trying is [EasyRTC](http://easyrtc.com) (might need some time to figure how to work with Node.js or iisnode...)

Comment: FYI: In a few days from now XSockets.NET will release a new version that supports WebRTC in both FF and Chrome. It will also have some other improvements.